# file upload using multer middleware with angular 7 mean stack not working

Tags: angular, express, multer

Please, I am using multer middleware for file upload in angular mean stack. I can't get req.file but can get req.body meaning the file is not being upload. 
At first when I upload I check the designated upload folder and I can't see anything but other text data can enter the mongoose database.

I then tried to res.send(req.file.filename) it says could not find property 'filename' of undefined. When I res.send(req.file) it returns null. but when I res.send(req.body) it returns the textual data keyed in from the html form. What have I done wrong?

I have gone through many suggestions to similar problem here on stackoverflow and other places online but none solved the problem for me.

Pls help

Find my code in vehicle.route.js below:

````
  path = require('path'),
  multer = require('multer'),

  app = express();

  const DIR = '../uploads/';
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const fileName = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now();
      cb(null, fileName)
    }
  });

  let upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage
  })

vehicleRouter = express.Router();

// Vehicle model
let Vehicle = require('../models/Vehicle');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads')));


// Get All Employees
vehicleRouter.route('/').get((req, res, next) => {
  Vehicle.find((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})



vehicleRouter.post('/register', upload.single('purchaseReceipt'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(req.file.filename)
  return;

/*vehicleRouter.post('/register', upload.single('purchaseReceipt'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(req.file)
  return;
  const vehicle = new Vehicle({
    fullName: req.body.fullName,
    purchaseReceipt: req.file.filename
  });
  vehicle.save().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Vehicle registered successfully!",
      userCreated: {
        _id: result._id,
        name: result.name,
        purchaseReceipt: result.purchaseReceipt
      }
    })
  })

  /*Vehicle.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })*/

  //res.json('from register vehicle')
  })

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './uploads')));
module.exports = vehicleRouter;```

I tried uploading straight but it isnt then I commented part of the code and tried to send back req.file.filename as response but it is saying: error: "Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined"

[the error code on console][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY9ob.png


vehicle-registration.component.html code ie the html form
```<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form method="post" [formGroup]="vehicleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fullName" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="preview" *ngIf="preview && preview !== null">
          <img [src]="preview" [alt]="vehicleForm.value.name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Upload Purchase Receipt</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="purchaseReceipt" />
      </div>-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Upload Purchase Receipt </label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control"  (change)="uploadFile($event)" formControlName="purchaseReceipt" name="purchaseReceipt"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" type="submit">Register Vehicle</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>```


vehicle-registration.component.ts code
````

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { VehicleService } from '../../service/vehicle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-registration',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-registration.component.css']
})
export class VehicleRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  preview: string;
  vehicleForm: FormGroup;

constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private vs: VehicleService) { 
    this.createForm()
  }

ngOnInit() {
  }

createForm() {
    this.vehicleForm = this.fb.group({
     fullName: ['', [Validators.required]],
     purchaseReceipt: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

uploadFile(event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.vehicleForm.patchValue({
      avatar: file
    });
    this.vehicleForm.get('avatar')
    // .updateValueAndValidity()

```
// File Preview
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  this.preview = reader.result as string;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
```

}

onSubmit() {
    if (!this.vehicleForm.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.vs.registerVehicle(this.vehicleForm.value)
       .subscribe(
         (res) => {
         console.log('Vehicle successfully registered!');
         console.log(res);
         },
         (error) => {
           console.log(error);
         }
       );
    }
  }

}```

The service file ie vehicle.service.ts

````
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VehicleService {

  baseUri: string = 'http://localhost:3000/vehicle';
  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerVehicle(data): Observable<any>{
    console.log(data);
    const url = `${this.baseUri}/register`;
    return this.http.post(url, data);
  }

}```
````

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you post your angular code so we see if you are actually sending the file to the backend - nodejs. thanks and waiting

new update!!

sorry i made a mistake wisdom. i am supposed to set the form data
use a formdata.set.... inside where you used the..

```
let image = new fileReader();
formdata: Formdata = new Formdata();  //updated!!

constructor(){}

preview($event){
this.image.onloadend = ()=>{
    //other codes
    this.formdata.set("image", $event.target.files[0]); // you can use this.formdata.append(...) if you want, but append keeps adding if maybe there is a retry due to error
}

this.image.readAsDataURL($event.target.files[0]);

}





onsubmit(){


//append or set other thing

this.vs.registerVehicle(this.formdata).subscribe(d=>{
// code here
})


}
```

using formData while uploading an image makes it easier to receive the file at the backend.

Comment: my vehicle-registration.component.html code ie the html form:

Comment: I have this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined. and it is pointing to the line of code where I wrote: this.formdata.set('purchaseReceipt', this.vehicleForm.value); I also declared formdata: FormData inside the class